# Wordpress wrong urls in admin panel pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, nginx

I have installed wordpress on my server a)

My static Website is on server b) and have domain.com and configured nginx to serve my wordpress from server a) on `example.com/blog/`

It works but I have one problem with posts and pages pagination.

Whole admin panel have urls like `example.com/blog/wp-admin[...]` and something like that.

But for pagination links in admin panel I have urls like `000.000.0.0(server a) IP)wp-admin[...]` and it's not working because I'm redirecting again to main `example.com/blog/wp-login/`

My wordpress address and site address are set to `example.com/blog`

My .htaccess file looks like below:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|svg|woff|woff2|font.css|css)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

How can I fix the pagination urls in my admin panel to get the url for pagination links like `http://example.com/blog/wp-admin/edit.php?paged=2` instead of `http://000.00.000.000/wp-admin/edit.php?paged=2`

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Does your WordPress site URL include the `http://` in front of `example.com`?

Comment: @RichardSmith I have http://example.com in both settings (WordPress address and site address)

Comment: @Robson Could you figure out why?

Comment: there is a ticket for this problem https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/36201